# Import an external C++ Library using Xcode 12

Tags: c++, shared-libraries

I am trying to import the lib curl library in my Xcode project.
There is what I have done and it did not work.
I downloaded the lib curl library from their site: https://curl.se/download/curl-7.73.0.tar.gz

Then I unzipped it and copied it in my project's folder.

Then there is the code I wrote to include it:

```
#include <curl-7.73.0/include/curl/curl.h>
```

But I get an error saying
'curl-7.73.0/include/curl/curl.h' file not found with  include; use "quotes" instead

Even after doing that it still don't load the library.

I tried to look for a solution on StackOverflow but it looks like all the solutions are not up to date. Anybody there can send me a brief explanation ?
Thank you